# ASP.NET issue setting CompareValidator.ValueToCompare

Tags: c#, asp.net, semantics, comparevalidator

I'm hoping someone can help. I've checked for an answer for this everywhere and can't find anything. I can't get my first if statement to "fire".

In my form, I have a text box for a user to enter quantity, and I'm trying to validate it to 150 when it's a product with "Foil" and "Standard" or "Printed" and "Mini" in its subcategory name.  If it doesn't have any of those 4 words, then the minimum quantity should default to 250.  Here's my code for the "quantity" text box:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" Text="Quantity" Width="300" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvQuantity" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtQuantity" ErrorMessage="Quantity Required" Display="None" ValidationGroup="Quote" />
<asp:CompareValidator ID="cmvQuantity" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtQuantity" ErrorMessage="Insufficient Quantity" Display="None" ValueToCompare="250" Operator="GreaterThanEqual" Type="Integer" ValidationGroup="Quote" />
<asp:CompareValidator ID="cmvQuantityText" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtQuantity" ErrorMessage="Quantity Required" Display="None" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Integer" ValidationGroup="Quote" />
```

And here's the code behind:

```
protected void rptProduct_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {

        ((CompareValidator)e.Item.FindControl("cmvQuantity")).ValueToCompare = ((Product)e.Item.DataItem).SubCategory.Category.Name.Contains("Foil") && ((Product)e.Item.DataItem).SubCategory.Name.Contains("Standard") ? "150" : "250";
        ((CompareValidator)e.Item.FindControl("cmvQuantity")).ValueToCompare = ((Product)e.Item.DataItem).SubCategory.Category.Name.Contains("Printed") && ((Product)e.Item.DataItem).SubCategory.Name.Contains("Mini") ? "150" : "250";
    }
}
```

For some reason, it only seems to work for the last condition, not the first, even if I switch the position of the conditional statements, it still only works for the last statement and never the first.
So I'm thinking it's a semantic issue?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think about what your code does, it should be obvious.

First, you do this:

```
((CompareValidator)e.Item.FindControl("cmvQuantity")).ValueToCompare = ((Product)e.Item.DataItem).SubCategory.Category.Name.Contains("Foil") && ((Product)e.Item.DataItem).SubCategory.Name.Contains("Standard") ? "150" : "250";
```

then, without further condition checking you do this:

```
((CompareValidator)e.Item.FindControl("cmvQuantity")).ValueToCompare = ((Product)e.Item.DataItem).SubCategory.Category.Name.Contains("Printed") && ((Product)e.Item.DataItem).SubCategory.Name.Contains("Mini") ? "150" : "250";
```

So if the `(Product)e.Item.DataItem` contains *Foil* and *Standard*, the first row sets the `ValueToCompare` to 150.

But on the next row, this is immediately changed back to 250 *unless* the `(Product)e.Item.DataItem` also contains `Printed` and `Mini`.

Try changing your code to this:

```
protected void rptProduct_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var validator = e.Item.FindControl("cmvQuantity") as CompareValidator;
        var product = (Product)e.Item.DataItem;
        if (validator != null)
        {
            if (product.SubCategory.Category.Name.Contains("Foil") && product.SubCategory.Category.Name.Contains("Standard"))
            {
                validator.ValueToCompare = "150";
            }
            else if (product.SubCategory.Category.Name.Contains("Printed") && product.SubCategory.Category.Name.Contains("Mini"))
            {
                validator.ValueToCompare = "150";
            }
            else
            {
                validator.ValueToCompare = "250";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, now this definitely makes sense and your code is definitely more readable, @user1429080 and should completely work, unfortunately it doesn't for some reason?  Now it won't set the ValueToCompare to 150 for either of the combinations, it's all defaulting to 250.  But I see where you're going.  I think maybe I'm not understanding how to use something here?

Comment: Does it find the `cmvQuantity` control? If you put a break point on the line starting with `if (product.SubCategory.Category.Name.Contains("Foil") ...`, is that break point ever hit? I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong with my sample unless you changes something else...

Comment: let me try that and let you know.

Comment: still trying to figure out what's going on, @user1429080.  Unfortunately I don't have a proper IDE (can't install Visual Studio Express on my machine), and my debugging is all manual.

Comment: Hi, user1429080.  I can see that it does find the cmvQuantity control,  but for some reason it's not finding "Foil" in the product name, in fact, it's not finding any of the keywords I'm looking for in the product name?  So maybe something's wrong with how I'm trying to obtain the name of the product from the database?

Comment: found the problem!  case sensitive.  needed to be: **Product**.SubCategory.Category  ugh.  Thank you so very much for your help!  I will put a check by your answer!  actually, for both you and @Harsh Baid, as both solutions worked, once the case sensitivity issue was worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Problem I see is that you set the `ValueToCompare` for the same Compare Validator control `cmvQuantity` twice which is completely wrong way because at last the last one to execute will be final change to the property's value so below is the implementation that should work in your case.

```
protected void rptProduct_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
       Product productInstance = e.Item.DataItem as Product; //safely type cast
       CompareValidator cmvQuantity = e.Item.FindControl("cmvQuantity") as CompareValidator; //safely type cast
       if (cmvQuantity != null && productInstance != null) //check if type cast suceeded and/or control was found.
       {
           if((productInstance.SubCategory.Category.Name.Contains("Foil") && productInstance.SubCategory.Name.Contains("Standard")) ||
              (productInstance.SubCategory.Category.Name.Contains("Printed") && productInstance.SubCategory.Name.Contains("Mini"))
           {
               cmvQuantity.ValueToCompare = "150";
           }
           else
           {
               cmvQuantity.ValueToCompare = "250";
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Some important points which might be helpful for you

- Try to find the object from page and take that in variable instead of finding in each new line. For example, instead of doing as follows:

  ```
  public void Method()
  {
      ((CompareValidator)e.Item.FindControl("cmvQuantity")).ValueToCompare = "Test value";
      ((CompareValidator)e.Item.FindControl("cmvQuantity")).ControlToValidate = "txtControlId";
  }
  ```

  Implement it as:

  ```
  public void Method()
  {
     CompareValidator cmvQuantity = e.Item.FindControl("cmvQuantity") as CompareValidator;
     if (cmvQuantity != null)
     {
         cmvQuantity.ValueToCompare = "Test value";
         cmvQuantity.ControlToValidate = "txtControlId";
     }
  }
  ```
- Don't add every new in If-Else-if for the same code blocks. For example

  ```
  if (test == 1)
  {
     txtControl.Text = "150";
  }
  else if (test == 2)
  {
      txtControl.Text = "150";
  }
  else
  {
      txtControl.Text = "250";
  }
  ```

  Implement it as:

  ```
  if (test == 1 || test == 2)
  {
     txtControl.Text = "150";
  }
  else
  {
     txtControl.Text = "250";
  }
  ```

Comment: unfortunately, this also didn't work, but thank you so very much for breaking things down and clarifying the steps for me. I'm examining those steps now.  I am still trying my hardest to learn ASP.NET, and I have inherited this code from a previous developer.  I'm just trying to make sense of it and be able to modify it to add new things.

Comment: Thank you, Harsh Baid.  Although I checked @user1429080's answer below, yours also worked (after I found out that the P in product needed to be capitalized.  Thank you very much for your help and thank you for breaking it down so I could understand!

Comment: sorry this is a late response, @Harsh Baid.  Couldn't vote up your answer because I don't have enough reputation points.  So sorry.

Comment: @ElenaPisanoMeghdir get involved in community ask questions or help others by answering to questions.. and eventually you will get good repo and knowledge also.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

here you have or condition so i would suggest you to differentiate the condition,

```
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        ((CompareValidator)e.Item.FindControl("cmvQuantity")).ValueToCompare = ((Product)e.Item.DataItem).SubCategory.Category.Name.Contains("Foil") && ((Product)e.Item.DataItem).SubCategory.Name.Contains("Standard") ? "150" : "250";
        ((CompareValidator)e.Item.FindControl("cmvQuantity")).ValueToCompare = ((Product)e.Item.DataItem).SubCategory.Category.Name.Contains("Printed") && ((Product)e.Item.DataItem).SubCategory.Name.Contains("Mini") ? "150" : "250";
    }
    else if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        ((CompareValidator)e.Item.FindControl("cmvQuantity")).ValueToCompare = ((Product)e.Item.DataItem).SubCategory.Category.Name.Contains("Foil") && ((Product)e.Item.DataItem).SubCategory.Name.Contains("Standard") ? "150" : "250";
        ((CompareValidator)e.Item.FindControl("cmvQuantity")).ValueToCompare = ((Product)e.Item.DataItem).SubCategory.Category.Name.Contains("Printed") && ((Product)e.Item.DataItem).SubCategory.Name.Contains("Mini") ? "150" : "250";
    }
```

and check whether its working or not.
i have not tested.

Comment: That certainly makes sense. Thanks so very much for the help, Purvesh! I will give that a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: This will not help. The problem is that the second row overwrites what the first row did for the _Foil_ + _Standard_ combination.

Comment: yeah, you're right.  unfortunately I tried Purvesh's solution and it did not work.  So I'm not quite sure how the second row is overwriting the first and what I should do?  Can you please explain that to me, I'm a little confused.  Thank you!

Comment: ah, could I use an OR in this case, @user1429080?  As in:

           `((CompareValidator)e.Item.FindControl("cmvQuantity")).ValueToCompare = ((Product)e.Item.DataItem).SubCategory.Category.Name.Contains("Foil") && ((Product)e.Item.DataItem).SubCategory.Name.Contains("Standard") || (Product)e.Item.DataItem).SubCategory.Category.Name.Contains("Printed") && ((Product)e.Item.DataItem).SubCategory.Name.Contains("Mini") ? "150" : "250";`
(and I'm not sure on my syntax here)

Comment: @ElenaPisanoMeghdir Yes, once you get all the parentheses to line up correctly. Basically that's what my suggested code does, albeit not on one single line (I think my code is more readable - it's easier to see what the code does).